# How to set a default Android drop down AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, autocompletetextview

I ran into an issue.  I have a bus arrival app with several color-coded bus buttons that if clicked, a drop down menu will be displayed from an AutoCompleteTextView according to the button clicked.  However, I also want to have a default drop down menu for the AutoCompleteTextView so that if I clicked on one of the buttons without selecting the listed item, the adapter automatically reverts back to the default adapter. After the parameter is selected, a submit button can be clicked to submit for the result.  I am resetting the adapter at onClickListener of the submit button, but this does not allow for resetting adapter after clicking on the color-coded bus button without selecting.  So how (or where) should I reset the default adapter?

This is my inherited AutoCompleteTextView class:

```
import android.content.Context;   
import android.graphics.Rect; 
import android.util.AttributeSet; 
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView; 

 public class InstantAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView { 

public InstantAutoComplete(Context context) { 
    super(context); 
} 

public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) { 
    super(arg0, arg1); 
} 

public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) { 
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2); 
} 

@Override 
public boolean enoughToFilter() { 
    return true; 
} 

@Override 
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, 
        Rect previouslyFocusedRect) { 
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect); 
    Log.d("IAC", "entered onFocusChanged");
   /*if (focused) { 
        Log.d("IAC", "focused, text="+getText());
        performFiltering(getText(), 0); 
        Log.d("IAC", "after performFiltering");
        showDropDown(); 

   } */
}
```

}

This is my default drop down list inherited from AutoCompleteTextView

[image: default drop down menu]

This is my cursor on one of the color-coded bus button

[image]

This is the drop down list from clicking the above button

[image]

P.S. I guess I need to reset the default adapter after the color-coded bus button loses its focus.  How do I do that?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make much sense to me, maybe include an image of the UI. An AutocompleteTextView is for typing into and showing suggestions based on what is entered, I don't understand why you would have separate buttons to show the options or submit them.

Comment: Ask your question properly, with point wise..

Comment: I actually inherited AutoCompleteTextView so that when I click a color-coded bus button, a list of buses will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

```
    button.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
           // code to execute when button loses focus
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks to everyone that posted.  :)